# Permissões em tempo de execução no android

Tags: android, android-permission

tenho um codigo no android studio que solicita ao usuario, permissão de utilizar o serviço de telefone (para pegar o imei)

bom, meu codigo esta funcionando perfeitamente, com um problema, ao entra na pagina, uma mensagem é exibida caso a permissao nao foi concebida, ate aqui, tudo ok , mas depois que o usuario aceita a permissao, como identifico que foi aceito e ai sim, segue o codigo?

meu codigo :

```
  checkedPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && checkedPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        showMessageOKCancel("É nescesssario ter Acesso a Informaçoes do Aparelho Para Obter Melhor Desempenho!",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                                REQUEST_CODE_PHONE_STATE_READ);
                    }
                });
        return ;
    } else
        checkedPermission = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
```

apos o usuário aceitar a permissão, minha activity fica fazia, e só carrega as informações depois que saio e entro nela de novo, como resolveria isto?

Answer (score 3):

O **[sistema de permissão](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/index.html)** do android é assíncrono: ele retorna imediatamente e, depois que o usuário responde à caixa de diálogo, o sistema chama o método **[onRequestPermissionsResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html?hl=pt-br#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[]))** do aplicativo com os resultados.

Para verificar se o usuário deu a permissão, é necessário substituir esse método em sua *Activity*

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PHONE_STATE_READ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                if (telephonyManager != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Imei: ".concat(telephonyManager.getDeviceId()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```